# MSSQL Support for PHP on IIS6

Tags: php, sql-server, iis-6

Trying to get mssql support for php working with IIS6

I require Microsoft Drivers 2.0 for SQL Server for PHP.

v3 was just released but requires NativeClient2012 (doesnt support win2k3)

All links for v2 now forward to v3.

Is there any other way to add support for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the [version 1.1](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=8059) might be suitable?

Alternatively you could look at installing and using [Microsoft's Web Platform Installer](http://www.microsoft.com/web/downloads/platform.aspx). From within this you then have options to install PHP (various versions) and MySQL as well as drivers for connecting to MSSQL from php code.

It's free software and a really easy way to install addons for IIS 6 & IIS 7